# Internet access Server 2012 R2

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a Server 2012 R2 that I connect through via RDC however we need to have this server be able to access the internet. When I try to access an internal site this seems to work fine. However when I try to access a simple webpage, I cannot get through to any outside site such as bing.com, yahoo.com or google.com.

I'm very new to server administration so any help would be greatly appreciated. I may not understand it (yet) completely though so please bear with me.

FWIW: The overall goal is to have this server run scripts that I write (or have already written) that pull data from various sites. This data is then transformed and uploaded to our databases for analysis.

Thanks in advance and again, please forgive my server administration ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the settings on the firewall between your server machine and the internet.  Can you reach external web sites from a browser running on the server machine?

Note: Exposing a server to the internet is a perilous thing to do.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I launch a browser and try to go to an external site such as bing.com or google.com and it times out. Pinging the same sites via command terminal also times out (as expected).

Comment: In that case you've got a firewall protecting your server.  You'll need to talk to the people who own the firewall if you absolutely must get out onto the internet from that server, but I repeat - that is a perilous thing to do.

To do what you describe, you should run your scripts on a separate machine, and have the script-running machine write the data to a specific location.  Then your server can read from that specific location.